# Select columns (not rows) in Bokeh Table Widget?

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I have a bokeh table that is linked to a plot, and is working as intended. Selecting a row in the table mutes all the non-selected rows in the plot display.

However, what if someone wants to select a column, and hide all other columns in the plot? Is this possible using a bokeh widget? Or does some custom code need to be written for this feature? I have attached to code used to produce the widget table on the bokeh website, as it is the most simple example I can think of (and quickest).

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn

output_file("data_table.html")

data = dict(
        dates=[date(2014, 3, i+1) for i in range(10)],
        downloads=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    )
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date", formatter=DateFormatter()),
        TableColumn(field="downloads", title="Downloads"),
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

show(widgetbox(data_table))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code with a JS callback that allows you to know the selected row and column.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable,TableColumn

column_list = ['col1','col2','col3']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = {key:range(10) for key in column_list})

columns = [TableColumn(field=col, title=col) for col in column_list]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280,selectable=True)

source_code = """
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-canvas')[0].children;

var row = '';
var col = '';

for (var i=0,max=grid.length;i<max;i++){
    if (grid[i].outerHTML.includes('active')){
        row=i;
        for (var j=0,jmax=grid[i].children.length;j<jmax;j++){
            if(grid[i].children[j].outerHTML.includes('active')){col=j}
        }
    }
}

console.log('row',row);
console.log('col',col);

cb_obj.selected['1d'].indices = [];
"""

source.callback = CustomJS(code= source_code)

show(widgetbox(data_table))
```

The line `cb_obj.selected['1d'].indices = [];` just resets the selected indices so that the callback can trigger even if the same cell is clicked multiple times

You can then do what you want with the row/column index

If you need to you can also "transfer" the values back to python by updating a ColumnDatasource with the row and column values.

I use bokeh 0.12.10 so this may require some change with the latest version

EDIT: tested with 0.12.16 and it still works

EDIT: update for bokeh 1.1.0

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable,TableColumn

column_list = ['col1','col2','col3']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = {key:range(20) for key in column_list})

columns = [TableColumn(field=col, title=col) for col in column_list]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280,selectable=True)

source_code = """
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-canvas')[0];

var active_row = grid.querySelectorAll('.active')[0];

if (active_row!=undefined){

    var active_row_ID = Number(active_row.children[0].innerText);

    for (var i=1, imax=active_row.children.length; i<imax; i++){
        if (active_row.children[i].className.includes('active')){
            var active_col_ID = i-1;
        }
    }

    console.log('row',active_row_ID);
    console.log('col',active_col_ID);

    var active_cells = grid.querySelectorAll('.active');
    for (i=0, imax=active_cells.length;i<imax;i++){
        active_cells[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    cb_obj.indices = [];
}
"""

source.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(args={'source':source},code= source_code) )

show(widgetbox(data_table))
```

Comment: So I have zero experience with JS, and am assuming I need to add a bit of code on to what you have provided to make the column selection rather than the row? I tried to implement this, and the table shows up and I can select a cell, but the plot it is connected to still only shows the row selections. Furthermore, the ability to select multiple rows / columns is lost. I may just need to read up on some JS?

Comment: @MattP. I just showed how to access the row and column index of a selected cell in a datatable. What you do with it is up to you, hard to tell without seeing all your code. And my example just works for one cell, but it could return a list of selected rows and columns indices instead with some editing

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.12.16` the built-in `DataTable` does not support any sort of column selection or click events. Looking at the descriptions of [Grid Events](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events) for the underlying SlickGrid implementation, it appears that `onClick` and `onHeaderClick` are supported at the low level. So the immediately accessible option would be [Extending Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) with a custom `DataTable` subclass. Otherwise you can submit a [GitHub feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss exposing these events somehow in the built in table.