# Bokeh DataTable - Return row and column on selection callback

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, bokeh

Using an on_change callback, I can get the numerical row index of a selection within a DataTable, in Bokeh. 
Is it possible to:
a) Get the column index
b) Get the values of the indexes (column and row headers)

Example code:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ColorBar, DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, HoverTool, Spacer, DatetimeTickFormatter

'''
Pandas
'''

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Apples': [5,10], 'Bananas': [16,15], 'Oranges': [6,4]})
df.rename(index={0:'A',1:'B'}, inplace=True)

'''
BOKEH
'''

sourceTableSummary = ColumnDataSource(df)
Columns = [TableColumn(field=colIndex, title=colIndex) for colIndex in df.columns] 
data_table = DataTable(columns=Columns, source=sourceTableSummary, index_position = 0, width = 1900, height = 200, fit_columns=False) 

'''
Funcs
'''

def return_value(attr, old, new):
    selectionRowIndex=sourceTableSummary.selected.indices[0]
    print("Selected Row Index ", str(selectionRowIndex))
    selectionValue=sourceTableSummary.data['Apples'][selectionRowIndex]
    print("Selected value for Apples ", str(selectionValue))
    # selectionColumnIndex?
    # selectionRowHeader?
    # selectionColumnHeader?


sourceTableSummary.on_change('selected', return_value)

curdoc().add_root(column(children=[data_table]))
```

This gives the following which can returns rows, and the values within the selection. This is ideal if I always want a single column returned. However the selection UI (dotted line) seems to suggest that the specific column is known, not just the row. 
If there's no way of attaining the selected column, can I look it up using both the Row Index and the Cell Value?

[Local Server Output & Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMPuH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses JS callback to show the row and column index as well as the cell contents. The second Python callback is a trick to reset the indices so that a click on the same row can be detected (tested with Bokeh v1.0.4). Run with `bokeh serve --show app.py`

```
from random import randint
from datetime import date
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TableColumn, DateFormatter, DataTable, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(dates = [date(2014, 3, i + 1) for i in range(10)], downloads = [randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)]))
columns = [TableColumn(field = "dates", title = "Date", formatter = DateFormatter()), TableColumn(field = "downloads", title = "Downloads")]
data_table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 400, height = 280, editable = True, reorderable = False)

text_row = TextInput(value = None, title = "Row index:", width = 420)
text_column = TextInput(value = None, title = "Column Index:", width = 420)
text_date = TextInput(value = None, title = "Date:", width = 420)
text_downloads = TextInput(value = None, title = "Downloads:", width = 420)
test_cell = TextInput(value = None, title = "Cell Contents:", width = 420)

source_code = """
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-canvas')[0].children;
var row, column = '';

for (var i = 0,max = grid.length; i < max; i++){
    if (grid[i].outerHTML.includes('active')){
        row = i;
        for (var j = 0, jmax = grid[i].children.length; j < jmax; j++)
            if(grid[i].children[j].outerHTML.includes('active')) 
                { column = j }
    }
}
text_row.value = String(row);
text_column.value = String(column);
text_date.value = String(new Date(source.data['dates'][row]));
text_downloads.value = String(source.data['downloads'][row]); 
test_cell.value = column == 1 ? text_date.value : text_downloads.value; """

def py_callback(attr, old, new):
    source.selected.update(indices = [])

source.selected.on_change('indices', py_callback)
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source, text_row = text_row, text_column = text_column, text_date = text_date, text_downloads = text_downloads, test_cell = test_cell), code = source_code)
source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)
curdoc().add_root(column(data_table, text_row, text_column, text_date, text_downloads, test_cell))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your answer here. I'd tried using JS for this before, and had a weird issue whereby my column index would be incorrect if I loaded over 12 columns. Couldn't figure out why this happened and using your JS and Callbacks, I couldn't recreate the issue. I plugged my pandas data into this and It's working perfectly. You even answered the 'detect another click on the same row' which I've encountered, but didn't ask, so thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: If you use a substantial amount of code from another answer it's nice to reference it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593326/select-columns-not-rows-in-bokeh-table-widget/50594578#50594578

Comment: Sounds fair. But please note that this is an open community place where people share their code so no one can claim his or her IP rights here. I created this code based on one of my local computer files to help others. I was not aware there was a similar post at the location you refer to and I hope you understand I am not going to search on the internet for each single line of code I post here to refer to it.

Comment: @Tony is there a way to do this with sortable columns?

Comment: Try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271790/js-code-to-reference-row-column-in-bokeh-datatable-erroring/56293041#56293041)