# Chart on click selection from data table in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I've taken the below code from another source - it is not my own code.

The code allows you to select a cell in the data table, and the 'downloads' data for that cell will chart based on the row of the cell selected.

How do I expand this code such that if I have multiple variables (eg. 'downloads' and 'uploads') and so more columns in the data table, I can chart data based on that cell (so where row AND column are important)? Alternatively, how can I define as a variable the column number of a selected cell (in the same way selected_row below can be used to define the row number)?

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, Div
import numpy as np

data = dict(dates = [date(2014, 3, i + 1) for i in range(10)],
            downloads = [randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)])
d_source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [TableColumn(field = "dates", title = "Date", formatter = DateFormatter()),
           TableColumn(field = "downloads", title = "Downloads")]

data_table = DataTable(source = d_source, columns = columns, width = 400, height = 280)

def table_select_callback(attr, old, new):
    selected_row = new[0]
    download_count = data['downloads'][selected_row]
    chart_data = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size = download_count)
    p = figure(title = 'bla')
    r = p.line(x = range(len(chart_data)), y = chart_data)
    root_layout.children[1] = p

d_source.selected.on_change('indices', table_select_callback)

root_layout = Column(data_table, Div(text = 'Select Date'))
curdoc().add_root(root_layout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use [my another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426404/bokeh-datatable-return-row-and-column-on-selection-callback/55433413#55433413) that uses a JS callback to access the row and column of the selected cell. This must be a JS callback as it uses HTML elements to walk through. So the steps are as follows:

1. Define a new `ColumnDataSource` that will contain the row and column number of a clicked cell

   `info_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(row = [], column = []))`
2. Use the JS callback from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426404/bokeh-datatable-return-row-and-column-on-selection-callback/55433413#55433413) to fill in the `row` and `column` values in this new `table_info_source` like this:

`callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=d_source,source2=info_source),code=source_code)`
`source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)`

3. Inside the JS callback store the `row` and `column` index like this:

   `source2.data = {row:[row],column:[column]};`
4. Access the `info_source.data` information in your Python callback to draw a plot

   `print (info_source.data)`

Both callback are attached to the same source but usually JS callback is executed first so the data should be available in the Python callback on time. Having the index of row and column of the clicked cell you should be able to retrieve the required data and draw your chart.

Comment: Thanks for the response - it seems from what you’ve said in the first bit above there is not, but just to clarify is there any way at all to do this without requiring JS or is that the only option? The team I am working in has expressed a preference for no JS usage

Comment: To my knowledge JS callback is the only option to get the column index of a clicked cell. Please note that Bokeh app in the browser is made of BokehJS models so it's 100% JS and it's kind of weird requirement to forbid JS. BokehJS is periodically synchronised with Python models via the Bokeh server. Eventually the `info_source.data` containing the column index will be accessible in Python code where you can do whatever you need.

Comment: I've tried following those instructions but the code I currently have (posted below) is printing {'column': [], 'row': []} - it's not populating with the information. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer and your code accordingly. Apparently the BokehJS can detect changes only when a new object is assigned to the `ColumnDataSource.data`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final working code (run from command line with `bokeh serve --show app.py`):

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Column, TableColumn, DateFormatter, DataTable, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(dates = [date(2014, 3, i + 1) for i in range(10)], downloads = [randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)]))
columns = [TableColumn(field = "dates", title = "Date", formatter = DateFormatter()), TableColumn(field = "downloads", title = "Downloads")]
data_table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 400, height = 280, editable = True, reorderable = False)
info_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(row = [], column = []))

source_code = """
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-canvas')[0].children;
var row, column = '';

for (var i = 0,max = grid.length; i < max; i++){
    if (grid[i].outerHTML.includes('active')){
        row = i;
        for (var j = 0, jmax = grid[i].children.length; j < jmax; j++)
            if(grid[i].children[j].outerHTML.includes('active')) {
                column = j; 
                source2.data = {row: [row], column: [column]};
            }
    }
}"""

callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source, source2 = info_source), code = source_code)
source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)

def py_callback(attr, old, new):
    source.selected.update(indices = [])
    print(info_source.data)

source.selected.on_change('indices', py_callback)
curdoc().add_root(Column(data_table))
```